# Cucumber ConcurrentEventListener implementation mechanism does not work when tests executed on Docker container

Tags: events, cucumber, listener, event-listener

I have implemented an event listener for Cucumber events:

```
public class AdccEventListener implements ConcurrentEventListener {
private static boolean stepFailed = false;


@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    System.out.println("register handlers!!!");
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::scenarioStartedHandler);
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::scenarioFinishedHandler);
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::stepStartedHandler);
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::stepFinishedHandler);
}

private void scenarioStartedHandler(TestCaseStarted event) {
    stepFailed = false;
}

private void scenarioFinishedHandler(TestCaseFinished event) {
    BaseTestUtils.reportInfoMessage("Scenario finish name is: " + event.getTestCase().getName() + " end of Scenario statement!");
    if (stepFailed) {
        Result result = event.getResult();
        setPrivateField(result, "status", Status.FAILED);
    }
}

private void stepStartedHandler(TestStepStarted event) {
    if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
        PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
        BaseTestUtils.reportInfoMessage("step name is: " + testStep.getStep().getText() + " end of statement!");
        ThreadLocalEvent.setStep(testStep);
    }
}

private void stepFinishedHandler(TestStepFinished event) {
    if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
        PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
        Result result = event.getResult();
        ThreadLocalEvent.setResult(result);
        if (result.getStatus().equals(Status.FAILED)) {
                if (!testStep.getStep().getKeyWord().startsWith("Given")) {
                    stepFailed = true;
                    setPrivateField(result, "status", Status.PASSED);
                }
        }
    }
}

private void setPrivateField(Object subject, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
        Field f = subject.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(subject, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

i have declared the Event Listener as a plugin in the CucumberOptions of the RunTests class.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "com.radware.bdd.AdccEventListener"},
    glue = {"com.radware.tests"},
    features = {"src/test/resources/Features"},
    strict = true,
    tags = {"@Functional"})
```

Now when i am executing tests on my local work station all is good. i am getting all events that were published in listener.

But, When the same project is executed on the docker container, listener does not get any events.
f. e. start Step, end Step events.

any idea what could cause it to not work under container?

Thank you.
Stas

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem.

When Maven tests were initiated from Jenkins or Docker container CucumberOptions arguments were passed. one of arguments was "--plugin". so my local definitions were overwritten.

Resolution is to add my custom plugin "com.radware.bdd.AdccEventListener" to the options passed through cli command.